# Using kivy plyer's vibrate from android service

Tags: android, python, kivy

I tried using plyer vibrate from main applicatin and it works as expected. But when I try to vibrate (the same with notification) from an android service then application crashes with SIGSEGV. I've tested it on two devices: lonovo tab (stack trace below) and on xperia z. In both cases I get SIGSEGV only the stack trace is a little bit different.

Can I use vibration/notification from within a service?
If I can then what to do with the SIGSEGV?

```
F/libc    ( 6826): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 6844 (Thread-1725)
I/DEBUG   (  164): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  164): Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/S8-50L/S8-50L:4.4.2/BMAIN/S8-50L_S000200_150121_ROW:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  164): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  164): pid: 6826, tid: 6844, name: Thread-1725  >>> com.myapp:PythonService <<<
I/DEBUG   (  164): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  164):     eax 1a117560  ebx 79bbbd08  ecx 00000000  edx 000000dc
I/DEBUG   (  164):     esi 1a115030  edi 79aaf970
I/DEBUG   (  164):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000043  xss 0000007b
I/DEBUG   (  164):     eip 7857ea75  ebp 79bbbcf8  esp 79bbba80  flags 00210287
I/DEBUG   (  164): 
I/DEBUG   (  164): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #00  pc 00198a75  /system/lib/libhoudini.so.4.0.8.45720
I/DEBUG   (  164): 
I/DEBUG   (  164): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba40  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba44  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba48  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba4c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba50  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba54  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba58  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba5c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba60  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba64  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba68  79bbba88  [stack:6844]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba6c  7857dcec  /system/lib/libhoudini.so.4.0.8.45720
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba70  1a117648  [stack:6840]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba74  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba78  79bbbcf8  [stack:6844]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba7c  7857e792  /system/lib/libhoudini.so.4.0.8.45720
I/DEBUG   (  164):     #00  79bbba80  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba84  78876ce0  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba88  79bbbb78  [stack:6844]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba8c  7857be8e  /system/lib/libhoudini.so.4.0.8.45720
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba90  79ab0160  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba94  79bbbb00  [stack:6844]
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba98  00000068  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbba9c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbbaa0  0000b30d  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbbaa4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbbaa8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbbaac  0000e440  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbbab0  00008180  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbbab4  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbbab8  00002779  
I/DEBUG   (  164):          79bbbabc  00002779
```

Comment: What kind of service is it? New style or old style?